# JQuery on() method not binding events but works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, mouseevent

I'm writing some TS code to generate a button dinamically, the button appear on page, but all events on it not works.
I already read answers about delegation and I using it, but the problem is not solved.

The most strange thing is that if I call `$("#myID").click()` or `.mouseover()` or `.mousedown()` in console, all events works correctly.

***EDIT AND CLOSE:***

Sorry for waste of time, I just put to my background the z-index css attribute to -100, and I don't know why, but the button was impossible to be clicked cause, even if it was visible, it was behind the background div.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz of your issue ?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here.

Comment: Have you verified that `this.enabled` is truthy?

Comment: Taplar, yes is true.
Prince I use requireJS and others dependencies, is a bit too long create a working stackblitz.

palaѕн I can't as I said to Prince, I'll add here all the code involved

Comment: @palaѕн I added code here

Comment: @Prince I added code here

Comment: @Taplar I added code here

Comment: Code is really unclear how any of it is linked together.

Answer (score 0):

> Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document. For example, instead of `$( "body" ).on( "click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment )` use `$( "#commentForm" ).on( "click", ".addNew", addComment )`.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

I suspect your delegation is too complex. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").click(function(e) {
    var item = $("<div>", {
      id: "image-button-1",
      class: "button"
    }).appendTo("#container");
    $("<img>", {
      src: "https://i.imgur.com/9yMnjGx.png"
    }).appendTo(item);
  });

  $("#container").on("click", "#image-button-1", function(e) {
    console.log("Click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Please don't refer to this, it is incorrect

Can you try this. Enclosing your logic in a function and passing it to jQuery ensures that it is called after the page is loaded completely.

When you are trying to bind event handlers to an element, you have to ensure that the element is actually present in the DOM.

```
this.htmlElement = "<div id='" + this.ID + "' class='" + this.cssClasses + "'>" + this.buttonImage + "</div>";
$("#" + this.idContainer).append(this.htmlElement);

$(function() {


  if (this.enabled) {
     $(document).on('mousedown', "#" + this.ID, function (event) {
         console.log("down");
     });

     $(document).on("mouseup", "#" + this.ID, function () {
         console.log("up");
     });

     $(document).on("click", "#" + this.ID, this.action);
  }
});
```

Comment: Delegate event bindings remove the need for the document ready, especially when binding on the document element.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar!,didn't know this.